# Python - Pandas read sql modifies float values columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas read_sql to validate some fields in my app.

**When i read my db using SQL Developer**, i get these values:

1. 603.29
2. 1512.00
3. 488.61
4. 488.61

But **reading the same sql query using Pandas**, **the decimal places are ignored and added to the whole-number part**. So i end up getting these values:

1. 60329.0
2. 1512.0
3. 48861.0
4. 48861.0

How can i fix it?

Comment: You could try adding `coerce_float=Flase` in `read_sql()`

Comment: That just removed the '.0' but didn't fixed the real problem. I've changed the sql query to convert that column to char for now.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a workaround for now.

**Convert the column you want to string**, then after you use Pandas you can convert the string to whatever type you want.

Even though this works, it doesn't feel right to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what SQL you are using? I just encountered a bit similar problem, which I overcame by defining the datatype more specifically in the query - here the solution for it. I guess you could use the similar approach and see if it works.

In my MySQL database I have four columns with very high precision
[image: Screenshot of SQL table]

When I tried to read them with this query, they were truncated to 5 digits after the decimal delimiter.

```
    query = """select  
               y_coef,
               y_intercept,
               x_coef,
               x_intercept
               from TABLE_NAME"""
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

However, when I specified that I want to have them with the precision of 15 digits after the decimal delimiter like below, they were not truncated anymore.

```
        query = """select 
               cast(y_coef as decimal(15, 15)) as y_coef,
               cast(y_intercept as decimal(15, 15)) as y_intercept,
               cast(x_coef as decimal(15, 15)) as x_coef,
               cast(x_intercept as decimal(15, 15)) as x_intercept
               from TABLE_NAME"""
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```