# Python - Pandas read_sql_query automatically rounds after 6 Digits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I'm trying to read data from sqlite3 database into a Dataframe. The problem is, that my numbers in the DB look like following `21.639929701230166`. And if I print my df the number gets rounded to `21.639930`. But I need the exact number for my PCA.

```
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT AvgRT FROM sensordata''', db_conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
```

I saw that there is float_precision for csv. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Is there anything for SQL?

I already tried to cast it (like seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70603287:

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT cast(AvgRT as decimal(25,25)) as AvgRT FROM sensordata''', db_conn)
```

but this results in the same number `21.639930` as before.

Comment: try doing this might work `pd.options.display.precision = 0`

Comment: If you load them as varchar/strings, your code works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pZhq1bL8QRomixKQjC2nRc/0.

Comment: @Ameya thanks that worked.Maybe my question were unclear, but I needed to change it to 20 or similar., to show the following decimals.  Now a following Question for understanding. Does it just display 6 decimals and calculates still with the normal number or does it calculate with the rounded number?

Comment: @lemon Thanks for your fast answer. pd.options.display.precision = 20, did it for me

Comment: Post it as the answer of this question and mark it as the accepted answer. @ngerber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the default precision in pandas is 6.

either you can use this `pd.options.display.precision = 0` handy thing or use one of the below.

```
# (1) Round to specific decimal places – Single DataFrame column
df['DataFrame column'].round(decimals=number of decimal places needed)

# (2) Round up – Single DataFrame column
df['DataFrame column'].apply(np.ceil)

# (3) Round down – Single DataFrame column
df['DataFrame column'].apply(np.floor)

# (4) Round to specific decimals places – Entire DataFrame
df.round(decimals=number of decimal places needed)
```